# How to get the images and load it in the variable name same as the image name

Tags: python, python-3.x, face-recognition

I want my code to load all the images automatically. For now I have to
write code for each images separately, but i want it to automatically get all the images from the directory, use the image name as the variable to load image file and also modify the image name to store the encodings.

```
p_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("p.jpg") 
P_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(p_image)[0]
```

Source for the face recognition code ( this is not my original code)
https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples/facerec_from_webcam_faster.py

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob

p_image_list = []

for each_image in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    p_image_list.append(face_recognition.load_image_file(each_image)
```

`p_image_list` contains all the images in current folder

Comment: `for each_image in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    p_image_list.append(face_recognition.load_image_file(each_image)
for (i=0, i<len(p_image_list),i++):
    known_faces.append(face_recognition.face_encodings(p_image_list[i])[0])`                         I did like this but i am getting an error( illegal target for variable annotation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary where items will be your variable names and have corresponding values of file names:

```
import os

files = os.listdir()
file_dict = {file : os.path.splitext(file) for file in files}
```

Comment: I am new to python so can you please give me an example.